# How to query products by their categories woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Im building a quick order form/ order table in Woocommerce

What I'm going for is something like this

```
Main category one
 Subcategory
        product
        product
 Subcategory
        product
        product

Main category two
 Subcategory
        product
        product
 Subcategory
        product
        product
```

My question is how do I query products under their correct categories

This is what i have so far

```
<?php

        $custom = array(

                  'post_type' => 'product', 
                  'posts_per_page' => 100,

        ); 

        $cust_query = new WP_Query( $custom );

        if ( $cust_query->have_posts() ) :
            while( $cust_query->have_posts() ) : $cust_query->the_post(); 

            $cat = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' ); 


            ?>

        <a href="#" class="link"><?php echo $cat[0]->name; ?></a>
        <div><?php the_title();?></div>



    <?php   endwhile; 
        endif;
```

This is querying each category one at a time I want all product that have the same category to be under the correct category with the category only printed once

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try with below code. Here i have assumed that you are having one level category only.

```
Main category one //level 0 
 Subcategory //level 1
    product
    product
Subcategory
    product
    product

Main category two //level 0 
Subcategory //level 1
    product
    product
Subcategory
    product
    product


<ul class="category-sidebar">   
<?php 
    $get_parent_cats = array(
        'parent' => '0', //get top level categories only
        'taxonomy'=>'product_cat',
        'hide_empty' => false
    ); 

    $all_categories = get_categories( $get_parent_cats );//get parent categories 
    foreach( $all_categories as $single_category ){
        //for each category, get the ID
        $catID = $single_category->cat_ID;

        echo '<li><a href=" ' . get_category_link( $catID ) . ' ">' . $single_category->name . '</a>'; //category name & link
        $get_children_cats = array(
            'child_of' => $catID, //get children of this parent using the catID variable from earlier
            'taxonomy'=>'product_cat',
            'hide_empty' => false
        );
        wp_reset_postdata();
        $child_cats = get_categories( $get_children_cats );//get children of parent category
        if(count($child_cats)>0){

            echo '<ul class="children">';
                foreach( $child_cats as $child_cat ){
                    //for each child category, get the ID
                    $childID = $child_cat->cat_ID;

                    //for each child category, give us the link and name
                    echo '<a href=" ' . get_category_link( $childID ) . ' ">' . $child_cat->name . '</a>';
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                    $args = array(
                                    'post_type' => 'product',
                                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                                    'tax_query' => array(
                                                        array(
                                                        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                                                        'field' => 'id',
                                                        'terms' => $childID,
                                                        ),
                                                    ),
                                );

                    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
                    echo "<ul>";
                    if($loop->have_posts()) {
                        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
                        $loop->the_post();
                        // do something
                        echo "<li><a href=".get_the_permalink()."> Product Name : ".get_the_title()."</a></li>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</ul>";
                }
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }else{
            //$catID
            wp_reset_postdata();
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'product',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                    'field' => 'id',
                    'terms' => $catID,
                ),
            ),
         );

         $loop = new WP_Query($args);
        echo "<ul>";
        if($loop->have_posts()) {
            while ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
            $loop->the_post();
            // do something
            echo "<li><a href=".get_the_permalink()."> Product Name : ".get_the_title()."</a></li>";
            }
        }
        echo "</ul>";
        }
    } //end of categories logic ?>
```